# How can I get the user profile data in passport google auth callback function?

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, google-oauth, passport.js

I'm using Passport Google auth for authentication. I am just confused about how I can pass the user profile data to the callback URL passed to passport google strategy.
[image]

In reference to the above picture, I have passed a callback URL to passport google strategy. I want the below user data object on this callback URL. How can I achieve this?

This is my callback path:
[image]

And the handler for this route:
[image]

I am getting only the code, scope params over there:
[image]

In Short, I want to return the custom jwt token to the frontend when the OAuth successfully completes. Can someone please help me achieve this?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After having a lot of search over the internet, finally I found the solution for this. To achieve this, you have to use the req argument in the callback and attach the user data with it as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

and then in the callback, you can get the user from req._user

[image]

Passport google strategy Code:

```
 passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: config.googleOAuth.clientId,
    clientSecret: config.googleOAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: `${config.endpoints.apiUrl}/user/gmail/oauth`,
    passReqToCallback: true
    },
    async function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      const profileJson = profile._json;
      const userData = {
        username: profileJson.email,
        firstname: profileJson.given_name,
        lastname: profileJson.family_name,
        picture: profileJson.picture,
        authType: 'oauth'
      }
      const user = await userCtrl.createOrUpdateUser(userData);
      req._user = userData;
      return done(null, user);
    }))
```

Callback Code:

```
 const OAuthCallback = async (req, res, next) => {
// function called after successfull oauth
console.log(req._user)
 }
```

Comment: Could you add a code snippet which one can copy instead of a picture of your code...

Comment: I have edited my answer with the code snippet, you can check it out now